# C# - How do I check if all files in folder have certain extension

Tags: c#

I need to check if all files in folder have a certain extension. I am trying to display a message/form if all the files in the folder have a .txt extension. Can anyone please provide code on how this can be done? Thanks.

Comment: no, this is not a code writing service. enumerate all (`Directory.GetFiles` for example) and break on the first occurrence of a `Path.GetExtension(file) != ".txt"`.

Comment: Read all file names, if any don’t match, show error message. Which part of this are you having problems with? Since Stack Overflow isn’t a “write this code for me” service you should find information for those parts with your favorite search engine and when you’ve tried to implement it you can ask help for a specific issue.

Comment: I never said just give me the code? I am trying to learn as well. Don't get all worked up lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its as simple as (but not limited to)

```
public bool DoAllFilesHaveExtension(string path, string extension)
{
   return Directory.GetFiles(path).All(x => string.Compare(Path.GetExtension(x),extension, StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase) == 0);
}
```

***Note***, no error checking, sanity checking or fault tolerance

---

**Additional Resources**

[Directory.GetFiles(string) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_)

> Returns the names of files (including their paths) in the specified
>   directory.

[Enumerable.All(IEnumerable, Func) Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.all?view=netframework-4.7.2)

> Determines whether all elements of a sequence satisfy a condition.

[Path.GetExtension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.path.getextension?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Path_GetExtension_System_String_)

> Returns the extension of the specified path string.

[String.Compare Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.compare?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.7.2#System_String_Compare_System_String_System_String_System_Boolean_)

> Compares two specified String objects and returns an integer that
>   indicates their relative position in the sort order.

Comment: Upvote from me, but case sensitivity many be an issue on that comparison.

Comment: also upvoted, but one question in the extension part what if I want to check multiple extensions such as .jpg , .jpeg and .png ?? does it allow multiple?

Answer (score 1):

> **TheGeneral** solution are fine than this but  i am just showing u another beginner level way

```
if (fileupload.HasFile)
     {
       if (CheckFileType(fileupload.FileName))
          {
            //it will come here if file extention will math your CheckFileType
          {
    }
```

Here you can define a type which you want to check

```
bool CheckFileType(string fileName)
        {
            string ext = Path.GetExtension(fileName);
            switch (ext.ToLower())
            {                    
                case ".txt":
                    return true;                          
                default:
                    return false;
            }
        }
```

Comment: This does not answer the question that has been asked.